# Using json_encode in a php web service

Tags: json, nusoap

I have developed a web service with php, PDO and nusoap. I use `json_encode()` function to returns an array as a result of my web service functions. In the array there are persian characters and result is like:

```
\u062c\u0627\u0645 \u0645\u0644\u062a\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u0631\u0648\u067e\u0627
```

I also used `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` inside `json_encode()` and the result is:

```
Ø¬Ø§Ù ÙÙØªÙØ§Û Ø§Ø±ÙÙ¾Ø§
```

How can I solve my problem to show persian characters correctly?